# Foreach em SQL para colocar um valor numa variável

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

O meu problema é que tenho uma subquery que funciona perfeitamente, mas para isso tenho de inserir o id que pretendo nas variáveis.

Na variável @mediaKM_mes faço select à tabela tblAbastecimento pelo id do carro;
na variável @kmInicio faço selelect à tabela tblCarro pelo id do carro;
e na @kmFeitos faço novamente select à tabela tblAbastecimento pelo id do carro;

Para que a minha query consiga preencher a tabela como estruturei precisava de passar o id_Carro que esta inserido para uma variável @id_carro para conseguir que as outras variáveis fossem buscar as informações pretendidas.

O que me acontece é que tenho de ser eu a colocar o numero e só preenche ou com o id 15 ou com o id 21

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Primeiro Declarei as variáveis desta forma:

@id_carro que é onde queria guardar o valor do id do carro que aparece em cada linha;

@mediaKM_mes é a média de km que o carro faz por mês e para dizer qual é o carro iria utilizar a variável @id_carro;

@kmInicio é os Km iniciais que o carro tinha quanto foi registado;

@kmFeitos que é os a soma dos km feitos por esse mesmo carro para somar com 
os @kmInicio e conseguir obter os km atuais.

```
-- VARIÁVEIS

declare @id_carro as int;

declare @mediaKM_mes as decimal = ( select -- nv3 
round( AVG( cast( kmMes as float)) ,0) as mediaKmMes from( select -- nv2
    marca,
    mes,
    sum(kmfeitos) as kmMes,
    sum(valorReal) as pagoMes,
    round( cast( avg(media) as float),1)as mediaMes from( select -- nv1
    *,
    case when Litros = 0 or kmfeitos = 0 then null else
    cast ((( Litros / kmfeitos) * 100) as decimal(18,1)) end as media from( 
select  c.marca as marca,
    a.KmFeitos as kmfeitos,
    MONTH(data) as mes, 
    valorPago - ValorDesconto as valorReal, 
    cast(valorPago / precoLitro as decimal(18,2)) as Litros from 
tblAbastecimento a join tblCarro c on a.id_carro = c.id_carro where 
c.id_carro = @id_carro) as nova1) as nova2 group by mes, marca) as nova3 
group by marca);

declare @kmInicio as decimal;
set @kmInicio = (select km_inicio from tblCarro where id_carro = @id_carro)

declare @kmFeitos as decimal;
set @kmFeitos = (select sum(KmFeitos) from tblAbastecimento where id_carro = 
@id_carro)


-- CÓDIGO

select -- nv3
    id_Carro,
    id_despesa,
    marca,
    descricao,
    v,
    km,
    cast(v / y_Meses as decimal(18,2)) as valorMensal,
    case when y_Meses > 12 then y_Meses - 12 end as mesPrevisto 
from( 
select -- nv2
    *,
    cast(Revisao / @mediaKM_mes as decimal(18,0))  as y_Meses
    from( select -- nv1
    *,
    km - (@kmInicio + @kmFeitos) as Revisao  from( select   c.id_carro as 
id_Carro,
    d.id_despesa as id_despesa,
    c.marca as marca,  
    d.descricao as descricao, 
    km as km, 
    valor as v from tblPrevistaCarro pc join tblCarro c 
    on pc.id_carro = c.id_carro join tblDespesa d on
    pc.id_despesa = d.id_despesa where c.id_carro = @id_carro) as nv1) as 
    nv2)as nv3
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Pode detalhar os cálculos que pretende efectuar?

Comment: @DiogoSousa: Para avaliar se é necessário ou não o uso de cursor, nos informe qual é o objetivo do código que pretende desenvolver bem como os cálculos que necessita obter.

Comment: @bruno editei o a minha pergunta na tentativa de ficar mais esclarecedora. Imagine que tenho 3 carros, cada carro tinha quilómetros diferentes, médias diferentes, e o que queria fazer era em cada linha saber de que carro se trata, colocar dentro de uma variável para que as outras variáveis conseguissem ir buscar a informação necessária para efectuar os cálculos. Obrigado

Comment: José Diz Já coloquei mais informações, espero não ser muito confuso, mas como disse, a minha lógica é: imaginando que tenho 3 carros, cada carro com quilómetros diferentes, médias diferentes etc, e o que queria fazer era em cada linha saber de que carro se trata, colocar dentro de uma variável para que as outras variáveis conseguissem ir buscar a informação necessária para efectuar os cálculos. Obrigado

Comment: Diogo, porque meu exemplo de cursor não serve para você? Copiei de um sistema de publicidade meu construído em 2012 e que até hoje todos os  dias faz o fechamento de caixa, portanto porque recebi voto contra?

Comment: @DiogoSousa: O que eu gostaria de saber é: (a) qual é o problema a ser resolvido? (b) Que resultado a consulta deve retornar? // Outras dúvidas: (c) Quais tabelas estão envolvidas? (d) Quais colunas das tabelas contém informações úteis para a consulta a ser montada? // Poderia acrescentar essas informações no texto do tópico, mas sem fazer qualquer menção ao código que postou?

Comment: @José Diz obrigado pela ajuda, já editei o meu problema... tenho alguma dificuldade em descreve-lo, mas acho que melhorou um bocado. Muito obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: @DiogoSousa: As perguntas que fiz em comentário anterior devem ser consideradas em um cenário em que não se tenha escrito uma única linha de código. Que não exista nem o código e nem as variáveis. O início. Aquele momento em que há somente as tabelas.  // A impressão que tenho é que um novo código terá que ser escrito, do zero.

Comment: @José Diz O que acha que devo melhorar ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não entendo por que você precisa utilizar um foreach nesse caso, se colocar tudo em uma query vc pode utilizar um in.

De qualquer maneira se realmente quiser usar o foreach pode fazer algo parecido com a resposta https://stackoverflow.com/a/18514429/8099197

```
declare @temp_cars TABLE (IDCARRO INT, DESC_CARRO VARCHAR(10))

INSERT INTO @temp_cars
SELECT 1,'BMW' UNION
SELECT 2, 'AUDI' UNION
SELECT 3, 'FUSCA'

DECLARE @LOOP int = 0
WHILE(1 = 1)
BEGIN
  SELECT @LOOP = MIN(IDCARRO)
  FROM @temp_cars WHERE IDCARRO > @LOOP
  IF @LOOP IS NULL BREAK
  declare @id_carro as int;
  SET @id_carro = @LOOP

  -- O SEU COODIGO DENTRO DO FOP
  SELECT * FROM @temp_cars WHERE IDCARRO=@id_carro
END
```

Comment: Na verdade eu não sei que solução usar, se o "in" desse não tinha qualquer problema em utiliza-lo

Comment: o seu código resulta, mas gera 3 tabelas diferentes e precisava q ficasse tudo numa só para a colocar numa datagridview, é possível?

Comment: A parte depois de
 -- O SEU COODIGO DENTRO DO FOP
  

Deve ser subistituida pelo seu código, coloquei o select só para mostrar que é feito o loop para cada um dos id_carro. Para colocar tudo em uma tabela só. VC pode criar outra tabela temporaria e inserir os valores que deseja nela. Depois do end vc da um select nessa tabela.

Comment: muito obrigado, criei a tabela temporária e inseri os dados nela e resultou, finalmente o meu problema está resolvido e você foi muito eficaz e muito directo, mais uma vez obrigado

Answer (score 0):

Você deve definir um cursor se precisar efetuar um loop através dos registros de sua querie. Para isso defina um cursor com sua query e as variáveis aonde será armazenado os atributos da tabela a cada novo incremento do loop, utilizando o operador INTO ("dentro")

Eu tenho um exemplo em mysql a lógica é a mesma, segue:

```
BEGIN 
    DECLARE ID        INT DEFAULT 0; 
    DECLARE num_rows  INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE loop_cntr INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE CURSOR_AFILIADO CURSOR FOR SELECT ID_AFILIADO FROM AFILIADOS; 

    OPEN CURSOR_AFILIADO;
       SELECT FOUND_ROWS() INTO num_rows;
       CURSOR_LOOP: LOOP 
           FETCH CURSOR_AFILIADO 
           INTO ID;

           IF no_more_rows THEN
              CLOSE CURSOR_AFILIADO;
             LEAVE CURSOR_LOOP;
          END IF;

            SELECT 
               COALESCE(SUM(SALDO),0) INTO CREDITO_MENSAL
            FROM     BALANCA_DETALHAMENTO_PUBLISHER 
            WHERE                                 
               ID_AFILIADO         = ID 

          SET loop_cntr = loop_cntr + 1;

      END LOOP  CURSOR_LOOP;
 END
```

> Repare no SELECT **BALANCA_DETALHAMENTO_PUBLISHER**  já estou utilizando a variável ID que está recebendo o valor da coluna ID da tabela  **AFILIADO**.

Adapte o exemplo ao seu SGBD sql-server e necessidades, espero que este exemplo lhe dê o entendimento. Abraços.

Comment: peço desculpa pelo voto contra, devo ter carregado e não notei, mas já corrigi... eu experimentei o código mas dá-me alguns erros por exemplo em FOUND_ROWS(), fica sempre a vermelho e estava a tentar resolver antes de dar algum feedback, assim que conseguir (ou não) eu volto a contactar... muito obrigado !

Comment: Opa Di vou conferir se não copiei algo errado! Mas pelo que entendi você está usando o SGBD sql-server correto ? Eu postei esse pedaço de rotina bem funcional de stored que construi faz o fechamento de caixa de um sistema de publicidade que trabalha por cliques mas é mysql! Me informe o seu SGBD talves eu consiga montar um cursor interator em sql-server.

Comment: sim o meu SGBD é sql-server. Fiz algo parecido que resultou, mas mostra em tabelas separadas e queria tudo numa só. Não está fácil